# OWIN IIS host deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I've opted-in to use OWIN IIS host for some concrete project and I got stuck in a deadlock when I want to send a request from a Web API resource.

Here's the `Startup` class code:

```
[assembly: Microsoft.Owin.OwinStartup(typeof(MyProduct.IdentityClient.Startup))]

namespace MyProduct.IdentityClient
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
    using Owin;
    using ServerMyWeb.Shared.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

And I've implemented some kind of proxy which does the actual HTTP request to other API (i.e. another host). When I perform that request, the proxy Web API enters in a deadlock.

```
    // Simplified sample of proxying a HTTP/GET request
    public virtual Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string apiRelativeUri)
    {            
        HttpRequestMessage request = ControllerContext.Request;

        request.RequestUri = new Uri("[URI to some API]");

        // Client == HttpClient singleton
        // HERE IS THE DEADLOCK. Client.SendAsync never returns/continues
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.SendAsync(request);

        // Some stuff to maniuplate response message... 

        return response;
    }
```

I've done similar implementations and it works in OWIN/Katana, and I'm sure that this has to do with IIS process and threading model, which has side-effects (maybe request thread can't be recovered to continue after HttpClient.SendAsync ends the asynchronous operation...).

**Do you have any news about this issue concerning OWIN IIS hosting and a possible solution (or perhaps I've skipped some configuration step when hosting OWIN on IIS...)?**

*NOTE: There's no `Task.Result`, `Task.Wait` or `Task.WaitAll`, or something like that during the execution of my code*.

### UPDATE:

I can confirm that this is an issue with OWIN IIS hosting, because I've minimally refactored ASP.NET Web API initialization to use old-school `Global.asax` and `GlobalConfiguration`, and same code worked flawlessly.

Comment: did you already try with HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false); ?

Comment: @FlorianMoser Sadly, yes, I tried this and no luck...

Comment: May be network tracing will give some hint. Here is link how to enable network tracing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PankajKapare I believe it's a threading issue, because when I set the `SendAsync` `Task` to a variable and I do `Thread.Sleep(...)` during a lot of seconds and I watch task status, it's always `WaitingForActivation`

Comment: I have similar problems with async/await in code with OWIN. On VS 2013. Do you have some new informations?

Comment: @polach.o No more info about this... Actually I've never hosted any app on IIS anymore... I'm using Katana.